# How to set std::vector<std::string> with custom string in each element

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdstring

i have configuration that i need to set into some kind of container 
i try to set into std::vector
but im getting compilation errors in both ways:

```
 std::vector<std::string> ConfigVec= new std::vector<std::string>();
  ConfigVec->at(0).append("00000\
              11111\
               00000");

    ConfigVec->at(1) = "11111\
             00000\
            00000";
```

what is the shortst way to do that without to many std::string declarations

Comment: Find out what regular the strings are, then generate strings by function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, drop the pointers and `new`<sup>1</sup>. Second, you are appending to elements that don't exist. Push strings back into the vector.

```
std::vector<std::string> ConfigVec;

ConfigVec.push_back("000001111100000");
ConfigVec.push_back("111110000000000");
```

and so on.

If you have a small number of strings, you can initialize the vector directly (unless you're stuck with a pre-C++11 implementation):

```
std::vector<std::string> ConfigVec{"000001111100000", "111110000000000"};
```

---

<sup>1</sup> * You were using `ConfigVec` as a pointer (assigning the result of `new` to it, and using `->` to access its members), but it isn't actually declared as one. This in itself is an error. In any case, there is little case for using `new` and raw pointers to dynamically allocated resources in C++.

Comment: @user63898 Because there is no reason to use it. And by using `new` you were just buying yourself a memory management problem.

Comment: but what is i like to pass the vector into other methods ?

Comment: @user63898 It is fine. If you don't want to make a copy, you pass a reference. But that has nothing to do with using `new`.

Comment: so when should i make new ?

Comment: @user63898 For example, when implementing a container (if you ever have to.) Currently, you still need to call `new` to instantiate a `unique_ptr`, but there is a `make_unique` function out there that lets you avoid this. It will be part of the next C++ standard. The point is that the standard library gives you many types and tools that allow you to avoid having to deal with `new` and `delete` directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<std::string> ConfigVec= new std::vector<std::string>();
```

This is "java-nese":  `std::vector<std::string> ConfigVec` is just a vectcor of string itself.
`ConfigVect.push_back("text")` will just add a string at the end.

Or did you mean

```
std::vector<std::string>* ConfigVec= new std::vector<std::string>();
//----------------------^-----------<< note taht!
```

In any case you cannot use `at` (or `[]`) on an empty vector, unlsess you first size it appropriately

Comment: Can you be more clear? This is not the telegraph office.